# UWP app using a Portable Class Library with resx based localized strings

Tags: xml, uwp, ivalueconverter

I'm trying to create a UWP app and reuse localization key/values that we store in an external database that devs/translators use. We export these into resx or other formats as needed depending on platform/application.
The new resw way of doing things is a no go because that would require modifying the existing key names or mangling them on export and adding a dependency of localization keys to XAML element names... That just sounds stupid. 
Luckily resx can work with UWP by using them in a Portable Class Library which can be referenced from XAML through IValueConverter. When running via debugging/emulator on Visual Studio, it works fine. My problem is when you create app packages and install it to a Win10 tablet for example, it doesn't work.

Example:

an implementation of IValueConverter used by XAML ends up calling the following code in the PCL 
// hardcoded CI for testing 
var cultureInfo = new cultureInfo("fr");

string value = Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(key, cultureInfo);

In Visual Studio where I can debug, it returns the correct value for the key (matches exactly the value in Resources.fr.resx) 
However after creating/installing the app package, value is null 
I have tried all combinations of Public/Internal/No Code generation for the default resx (Resources.resx) and the specific language resx. None worked. What is app packaging doing that makes it not work? Is this a UWP bug or am I doing something wrong?